# Scala List difference with index information

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have two Lists

> val l1 = List(1,2,3)
>
> val l2 = List(1,3,3)

with

> l1.diff(l2)

I can find the difference in the list; at the same time I am interested in index where the difference found also; can i know what is the solution in scala ?

Note : All the time both the list size is going to be same.

Comment: I made a close request, since it is not apparent what he wants to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just add indexes to both lists and diff then:

```
val diff = l1.zipWithIndex.diff(l2.zipWithIndex)
-> List((2,1)) // different value is 2 and index is 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val indexes = (l1 zip l2 zipWithIndex).filter(x => x._1._1 != x._1._2).map(_._2)

val indexesWithDiffValues = (l1 zip l2 zipWithIndex).filter(x => x._1._1 != x._1._2)
```

this code will give you a list of indexes you want.

Answer (score -1):

Another way which shows you very easy which list and where you can find the value:

```
l1.diff(l2).map(v => (v, l1.indexOf(v), l2.indexOf(v)))
// res6: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((2,1,-1))
```

Comment: Doesn't work if one of the values in a "not the same" position turns up earlier in the list: `val l1 = List(1,2,3,1);val l2 = List(1,3,3, 2);l1.diff(l2).map(v => (v, l1.indexOf(v), l2.indexOf(v)))` gives `List((1,0,0))`